# Android installing an apllication by code......and start an application with some arguments

Tags: android, adb

i'm really freaking out cause i don't know how to find example or documentation for my issue. I developed a kind of Ndroid Market that let you download .zip file and save the in the sd (ex root\download). Each zip contains an icon and an html web application (ex. `Icon1.ico` and `Application1.html`). When the download is finished MyMarket unzips the application1.zip file and puts it in a folder.

What I would like to do is to find out how to add the `application1.html` to the list of my application using `icon1.ico` as icon, basically I'd like that if someone clicked on the menu button of the phone in the list of my application is shown one with the `icon1.ico` image, but how to to that? I can't find any code example.

And then the second step. I have to develop both this alternatives and then someone else will choose beetween them

- When i click on the icon1 on the list application the default browser is opened and the html application is  run inside it....
- The most difficul, when i click on the icon1 MyMarket Application is opened but with a parameter, like when in java you run program1 but with one argument that you can retrieve in the argv array. So for esample if i click on the MyMarket icon or on the Icon1 icon the same application is started but then MyMarket check if the "argv" is empty and if it's not and for exmaple there is a string "application1" it open another activity with a webview and run the html file inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how to to that?

That is not possible for most home screen implementations. The only things shown in a standard launcher are activities, from APK files, flagged as belonging in the launcher. You cannot create these on the fly.

You are welcome to make your own home screen that offers your desired behavior as a feature.

Comment: So basically in the home screen are shown only icon coming from apk files.........so both the scenarios are impossibile??? In the second one my icon would be linked to a standard application......i already have one called MyMarket the only difference is that i would lunch the same application but passing  an argument......is not anything something like argv in android? Link explaninig how to implement my custom home screen?

Comment: @user280560: The home screen itself may have shortcut icons to various things. However, there are no APIs for you to create them programmatically.

Comment: Tnx to yur 2 keywords shortcuts and home scree i found out this.....http://codinggeek.org/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/     is it what i want.......if i put in extras my string and i call mymarket it should work for the second scenario???

Comment: @user280560: This technique is not recommended. This is an internal implementation, not part of the Android SDK. It will not work on all home screen implementations. It may not work on all past versions of Android. It may not work in future versions of Android, as Google is not obligated to maintain internal undocumented interfaces. Please do not use this.

Comment: ok tnx...........so i will say that both scenarios are impossible and to launch an app you have to open the market, go to my applications, scroll the list and choose the one you want............then a webview will start........

Comment: Never heard about OpenApp market.....it's a  html5 store, that is basically what i'm trying to do http://openappmkt.com/ after you serarch for an app, you click in download and a toast "shortcut added to your home screen is shown" the you can click on it and the app is opened, actually teh browser with the app inside cause are html apps.that's basically my first scenario..it's a really famous market so it means that it is supposed to work,but how they do that? In that deprecated way? I tried it on my phone but it actually doesn't add the shortcut,maybe as you said is not workinf on all devices